# Is there a way to run guile function from command line

Tags: scheme, guile

So I have a simple `file.scm` file with following code in it:

```
#!/usr/bin/guile -s 
!#
(define (printer arg)
  (display arg))
```

I know you can execute it inside guile repl by doing a `(load "file.scm")`, and then by invoking the function like `(printer "this")`.

Is there is any way to run that function through the **command-line** terminal
such as `guile "file.scm" (printer "this")` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/Command_002dline-Options.html#Command_002dline-Options), something like

```
guile -l file.scm -c '(printer "this")'
```

will work.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the `-e` flag

```bash
guile -e printer file.scm 1 2 3
```

Or better yet

```lisp
#!/usr/bin/env -S guile -e printer
!#

(define (printer args)
  (display args))
```

and run as

```bash
./file.scm 1 2 3
```

Many other (official) Guile Scripting examples: https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/Scripting-Examples.html